# Why does adding a MouseArea with anchors.fill: parent cause the rows to stack up on one another?

Tags: qml

Given that this `ListView` works fine:

```
ListView {
    id: myListView
    model: myListModel
    anchors.fill: parent

    delegate: Row {
        id: row
        spacing: 5
        Text {
            text: id
            width: 25
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        Text {
            text: description
        }
    }
}
```

Why does adding a `MouseArea` with `anchors.fill: parent` cause the rows to stack up on one another?  How do I get back the automatic vertical spacing that I had before adding `MouseArea`?  I have already tried putting the `Row` in a `Rectangle` and also in a `Component`.

```
ListView {
    id: myListView
    model: myListModel
    anchors.fill: parent

    delegate: Row {
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: myListView.currentIndex = index
        }
        id: row
        spacing: 5

        Text {
            text: id
            width: 25
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }

        Text {
            text: description
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The items stack up for a simple reason: their height is **not set**. A delegate must **always** have an height set. Since you did not specify one, delegate height is zero and the enclosing text is rendered over the same `y` (zero), stacking up.

However, that's not the only problem here. You defined the `MouseArea` to be anchored. `Row`s, as well as `Column`s, force a specific arrangement for items inside themselves. Adding anchors can interfer with this automatic mechanism.
Also [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-row.html) are clear about this. You can read that...

> Row is a type that positions its child items along a single row. It can be used as a convenient way to horizontally position a series of items **without using anchors**.

...and also that...

> [...]**since a Row automatically positions its children horizontally**, a
> **child item** within a Row **should not set** its **x** position or horizontally
> **anchor** itself using the **left**, **right**, anchors.**horizontalCenter**, **fill or
> centerIn** anchors.

*Probably, the anchoring error generates an inconsistent state such that `Row` does not inherit height from the enclosing text, as it did without anchoring items. This in turn results in the zero height and the stacking.*

In this particular case, you can include the `Row` inside an `Item` and apply the filling `MouseArea` to the latter. The resulting code, *with also the delegate height and width correctly set*, would look similar to the following (mind you, I've removed roles and model in your code since the latter was not available in the provided code snippet):

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible:  true
    width: 200
    height: 300
    
    ListView {
        id: myListView
        model: 20
        anchors.fill: parent
        
        delegate: Item {
            width: myListView.width
            height: text1.height            // set the height!
            Row {
                id: row
                anchors.fill: parent
                spacing: 5
                
                Text {
                    id: text1
                    text: "id"
                    width: 25
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                }
                
                Text {
                    text: "description"
                }
                
            }
            MouseArea {                     // fills the delegate Item, not the Row!
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    myListView.currentIndex = index
                    console.info("Area clicked! Index: " + index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```